# How to DI an EF 6 Service with dynamic connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection

Our DB is setup with one admin DB and multiple client DBs. When the user logs in (via the admin DB), we determine which client DB they should use and return that connection string for future use (store in the session).

I really like the way [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27528909/156611) deals with working with EF6, and would like to implement something like this, but am not sure how I can use DI and update the connection string as well.

The actual update of the connection string on the DbContext is straight forward using DbConnection. It's just the ability to cleanly create and update the DbContext via some DI mechanism that I am not seeing at the moment.

Comment: Its not clear what is your problem

Comment: This depends on how you're dbcontext is being constructed, and the DI framework you are using.

Comment: @Eris I haven't yet chosen a DI framework. I'm looking at Unity and StructureMap at the moment. Do any of the DI frameworks out there solve it more elegantly than others?

Comment: @Evk I don't want to have to specify the connection string whenever I create the client DbContext. The admin DbContext is simple since it will use the connection string from web.config. Somehow, I'd like to use DI to help with the "injection" of the connection string for that user into the client DbContext.

Comment: What about creating a decorator class for ClientContext that has HttpContext injected container.RegisterType<HttpContext>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current)); and then in the ctor of ClientContext, get the connection string from the session and update the contained DbContext?

Answer (score -1):

DI is compile time process, however you can do some decisions at runtime using factory pattern to instantiate a class(from a set of classes that inherit from same interface) depending on some condition

as a solution for your problem you can use a static function to return the appropriate connection string, no DI is required

```
public static class ConnectionStringPorvider
{
    public static string getConnectionString()
    {
        switch(dbName)
        {
         ....
        }
    }
}
```

and in your data context class

```
base(global::[class name space].ConnectionStringPorvider.getConnectionString(dbName), mappingSource)
```

Comment: While I agree 100% with your answer (even though you could make it a little more clear for the OP), DI is not a "compile time" process, it is a composition time (startup) process.

Comment: Static classes can't be mocked, injected, and are completely inflexible.

Comment: Yeah, I briefly thought about doing that but am hoping there is a more elegant, more testable way to do this, hopefully, using DI.

Comment: It is a startup process but I'm not sure that you can make later decisions depending a condition, i read an article one about using decorators but i'm not sure. factory pattern could be applied in this case which i think the most suitable.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the static on the class. I would not recommend that. Better to make an abstract factory that is not static to inject into the repository class. The abstract factory then decides at runtime via a public method which instance to create.