# EF SQL changed when passing predicate as Parameter to Where Clause

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

EF is generating different SQL for the for two similar statements listed below

```
var test = dbcontext.Persons.GetAll()
                            .Where(c => c.PersonID == 2)
                            .Select(c => c.PersonName)
                            .FirstOrDefault();`
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[PersonName ] AS [PersonName ]
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP (1)
         [Extent1].[PersonName ] AS [PersonName ]
     FROM 
         [dbo].[ApplicationRequest] AS [Extent1]
     WHERE 
         [Extent1].[PersonID ] = @p__linq__0) AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0= "2"
```

I am using the above statements at multiple places with different `Where` condition; to consolidate logic in one place I am passing the condition as a parameter

```
Public Void PassPredicate(Func<ApplicationRequest, bool> ReqFunc)
{
    var test = dbcontext.Persons.GetAll()
                                .Where(ReqFunc)
                                .Select(c => c.PersonName)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I am calling the function as

```
PassPredicate(c => c.PersonID == 2);
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
    [Extent1].[PersonName ] AS [PersonName ], 
    [Extent1].[DOB] AS [Dob], 
    [Extent1].[Height] AS [Height],
    [Extent1].[BirthCity] AS [BirthCity], 
    [Extent1].[Country] AS [Country],
FROM 
    [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1]
```

If you look at the second SQL, it is quite alarming: it is pulling all info (columns and rows). It doesn't have where clause and selecting all columns.

The where condition is being applied after the results were returned from DB.

The only difference in the second statement is I am passing condition as parameter instead of having condition inside where clause.

Can anyone explain why the difference?

Comment: `var test = dbcontext.Persons.GetAll().Where(c => c.PersonID == 2).Select(c => c.PersonName).FirstOrDefault();` why are you not using simple statement like `var test = dbcontext.Persons.FirstOrDefault(c => c.PersonID == 2).Select(c => c.PersonName);`

Comment: I am bit tied on using other than GetALL.Actually we are not using the exact syntax..we are using something like PersonsRepository.GetAll()...The repository is exposing only limited functionalitites

Comment: oky but i think it uses  extra resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `ReqFunc` type is `Func<ApplicationRequest, bool>` you're using `Enumerable` extensions, so your code (`Where`, `Select`, `FirstOrDefault`) will be executed in-memory.

To fix this, just change `ReqFunc` to `Expression<Func<ApplicationRequest, bool>>` to use `Queryable` extensions:

```
Public Void PassPredicate(Expression<Func<ApplicationRequest, bool>> ReqFunc)
{
    var test = dbcontext.Persons.GetAll().Where(ReqFunc).Select(c => c.PersonName).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Worked..That's why you have to thoroughly understand the concept before getting into the coding...instead of getting instant solutions through stack overflow..I hate to do it...but I am still doing it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The IQueryable Where takes an `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`, NOT a `Func<TSource, bool>`, so a different overload of Where is being called, causing the query to execute and the result to be returned as an IEnumerable instead of an IQueryable.

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
this IQueryable<TSource> source,
Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate
)
```

Pass your Func as an Expression and you should get the desired behavior.