# Nsubstitute: How to create a fake inside a generic class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, nsubstitute

I am using Nsubstitute for mocking. To reduce code I want to write a generic class that fakes a generic attribute:

```
public class Tester<TValue>
    where TValue: IValue
{
    // this is used inside the class in other methods
    private TValue CreateValue()
    {
        return Substitute.For<TValue>(); // here the compiler has an error
    }
}
```

This code gives a compile error at the marked place:

> The type 'TValue' must be a reference type in order to
>   use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'Substitute.For(params object[])'

This seems obvious, because the implementation of the `Substitute`class looks like this:

```
public static class Substitute
{
    public static T For<T>(params object[] constructorArguments) where T : class;
}
```

What I am wondering about is, why then such a code is possible: `Substitute.For<IValue>()` and does not raise an error. Can anybody explain how to do the generic class with the faking right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should work:

```
public class Tester<TValue>
    where TValue : class, IValue
{
    // this is used inside the class in other methods
    private TValue CreateValue()
    {
        return Substitute.For<TValue>(); // here the compiler has an error
    }
}
```

[The type must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451120/the-type-must-be-a-reference-type-in-order-to-use-it-as-parameter-t-in-the-gen) may be worth a read.

*The reason it is necessary is that `Substitute.For` specifies a reference type (`class`). Thus, any generic callers to it (like yourself) need to specify the same `class` constraint.*

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have seen the constraint, that NSubstitute needs a class as generic parameter. I wondered, that it is possible to use an interface with `Substitute.For<IValue>()`. For my case it is not possible to constraint the `TValue` generic parameter to a class, as I need it for interfaces.

Comment: Can you update your post with your interface definition (i.e. file) for `IValue`, and also the files for every class / struct that implements `IValue`?

Comment: Note that `class` in the context of my code sample doesn't mean "class rather than interface" it means "class rather than struct". Did you try my above code for your purposes? Did it work?

Comment: The note about the keyword `class` opened my eyes. Yesterday I tried to manage it with the class constraint and it didn`t work. Today everything is fine. Maybe it was something else. Thank you very much. You are great.