# The type T must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter while using interface

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface, moq

I got the error for the below code

```
public static Moq.Mock<T> CreateInstanceOfIMock<T>() {
    return new Moq.Mock<T>();
}
```

I have [*solved*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451120/the-type-must-be-a-reference-type-in-order-to-use-it-as-parameter-t-in-the-gen/6451237) the error it by using referred `class` type. See this below code

```
public static Moq.Mock<T> CreateInstanceOfIMock<T>() where T : class
{
    return new Moq.Mock<T>();
}
```

---

Now I want to move this `var mockColorsRepository = new Moq.Mock<IColorsRepository>();` code into common code by using `generics`. here `IColorsRepository` is an `interface`. So I made an interface reference for `T` instead of `class` like this below code

```
public static Moq.Mock<T> CreateInstanceOfIMock<T>() where T : interface
{
    return new Moq.Mock<T>();
}
```

But am getting `The type T must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter` error. How can I refer `interface` instead of `class` to `T`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to do it like this: `where T: class, IColorsRepository`. Or if you mean _any_ interface - there is no such constraint.

Comment: @Evk `class, IColorsRepository`  it showing error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`class` and `struct` in [generic type constaints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) do not mean the same thing as the `class` and `struct` declarations that are used to declare class or struct types. Instead, they only restrict whether a generic type argument is a *reference type* (`class`), or a *value type* (`struct`).

So when you do `where T : class` you are *not* saying that `T` needs to be a class, you are saying that `T` needs to be a reference type. Similarly `struct` for value types.

Interfaces on their own do not have this property, so an interface can be implemented by both a reference type and a value type. As such, restricting your type to be of an interface does not really make sense there.

In your case, Moq requires you to pass a *reference type*, so you need to transitively carry over that type constraint in all your helper methods:

```
public static Moq.Mock<T> CreateInstanceOfIMock<T>()
    where T : class
{
    return new Moq.Mock<T>();
}
```

That’s all you need to do to create a mock of *any* valid type. You can use it with an interface using `CreateInstanceOfIMock<IColorsRepository>()` or any other type.

Of course, at that point, the method does not really make that much sense since it does not give you any benefit over just instantiating the mock yourself.

Comment: If am using `class` instead of `interface` then how it would be a `type safe`?

Comment: I don’t know what exactly *you* are referring to when you say “type safe”, but since this is a generic method, and since you are satisfying the generic type constraint of the `Mock<T>` type, your method is “type safe” in that it will allow you to create a `Mock<T>` type for *any* valid `T` that you pass to your function. And `T` is not limited to being an interface, you could pass a concrete class as well (which is also perfectly fine with Moq).

Comment: I just found that you can do both here. I'm using a custom base class for a bunch of unit test classes that do similar things while still being different. My base class declaration looks like `public class MyTestClassBase<T> where T : class, IMyInterface`.

Just `where T : IMyInterface` obviously didn't work, and `where T : class` feels too generic imo.

Answer (score 5):

There's no generic constraint in C# to enforce that a type argument is an interface. But `where T : class` is *really* "where `T` is a reference type" - it includes interfaces.

If you wanted to enforce that `T` is an interface rather than a class, you could perform an execution-time check using `typeof(T)` within the method, but in this case it sounds like you don't really *need* to constrain it to be an interface.

I'm not sure that the "helper" method is particularly useful though - if you compare:

```
var mock = Helper.CreateInstanceOfIMock<Foo>();
```

and

```
var mock = new Moq.Mock<Foo>();
```

or even (unless you have `Mock<T>` as another type somewhere) just a `using Moq;` directive and

```
var mock = new Mock<T>();
```

The latter seems just as readable and shorter... it makes sense if you're going to add more logic in your method, but if it's only ever going to call the constructor, I don't think I'd bother with it.